# How to effectively combine Ars Magica's Agent rules with Reign's Company rules?

Tags: campaign-development, homebrew, ars-magica-5, realm-management, reign

This question was originally posed hypothetically in this [Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7086/any-mechanics-out-there-for-developing-and-maintaining-a-spy-information-network/7099#7099) and ensuing comments.

I am attempting to do something very similar to this as seen in this [Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58693/how-to-build-a-flexible-and-scalabe-system-for-pcs-npc-organizations).  In that question I am looking for any good approach to building a system that allows interesting, realistic, and meaningful PC-created organizations.

@Brian Ballsun-Stanton suggested that this particular approach (combining these two rule sets) would be quite easy, but the question has yet to be explicitly asked.

So, for those who may have attempted/succeeded in merging these realm-management systems:
**How did you do it?**

It would be helpful if you also include at least a brief description of how effective the resulting system is, existing difficulties with it, and any possible improvements.

Answer (score 1):

To start off then I have no experience with the Ars magica, but I believe my experience would work as a charm.

I have been playing a little with [the company rules](http://www.gregstolze.com/Company_Reference.pdf) for my games, what I have done is to add positions within each company for each Quality then connect there main attributes/skills to the ability to get the "Temporary Raises" on the Qualities.

There is still question of character skills interaction with Might and a Mass Combat System, Character wealth conversion to Treasure and back and controls on that as Treasure is much much more then gold and sometimes gold is worthless as Treasure, and also how to handle the followers that help build your Sovereignty and the occupation of Territory.

here is a quote from GregStolze that helped me somewhat.

> **Re: Help Using REIGN's Company Rules With Other Games**
>   The comments here seem to have things covered. The Company rules were
>   designed to be loosely coupled, so the only major point of interface
>   is "Raising the Pool." I really don't think there should be any
>   unexpected effects that swarm out of nowhere to bite on you. The only
>   problem I anticipate is that the success/failure curve in the ORE is
>   quite different from D20 stuff. But given the disconnect between the
>   circumstances (personal vs. nation-wide), the disconnect between
>   mechanics ("Man, we busted our humps and STILL couldn't get a set?")
>   may work just fine. The relative rarity of the ORE rolls (because PCs
>   can scurry around doing all kinds of stuff, while Companies work on
>   the scale of months) should, I think, make them more dramatic and
>   breathtaking. That's the plan, anyhow.
>
> -G.
>
> [**GregStolze, 2011-MAY-13 at forum.rpg.net**](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?575050-Help-Using-REIGN-s-Company-Rules-With-Other-Games)